# Remove string endings with regex and preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to do a simple replace. I try to understand regular expressions but it's like Chinese to me. I've read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression but frankly that is still too complex for me to understand.

I got the following 6 strings (each row is a separate variable):

```
$sampleArray[] = "Pyromancer 6,52 Pack - 19,99€";
$sampleArray[] = "Dreadnought Pack - 36,99€";
$sampleArray[] = "Citizen Pack - 45,99€";
$sampleArray[] = "Colonies - Pyromancer Pack - ";
$sampleArray[] = "Colonies - Dreadnought Pack - ";
$sampleArray[] = "Colonies - Citizen Pack - ";

foreach($sampleArray as $package_name) {

    $pattern = '/(\s-\s[0-9]+,[0-9]+€)|(\s-\s)$/';
    $package_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $package_name);
    echo $package_name;
}
```

The result that I want is to have the part at the end removed:

```
Pyromancer 6,52 Pack
Dreadnought Pack
Citizen Pack
Colonies - Pyromancer Pack
Colonies - Dreadnought Pack
Colonies - Citizen Pack
```

What I tried through trial and error is:

```
$pattern = '([0-9]+,[0-9]+â‚¬)';
$package_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $package_name);

$pattern = '( - )';
$package_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $package_name);
echo $package_name;
```

This however gives me the following result:

```
Pyromancer 6,52 Pack
Dreadnought Pack
Citizen Pack
ColoniesPyromancer Pack
ColoniesDreadnought Pack
ColoniesCitizen Pack
```

Anyone care to help me point out the final thing that I'm missing to only change the string at the end?

Also is it possible to put this into one replace function instead of going through it multiple times?

Update: I made a fiddle here: http://viper-7.com/1dXwXQ

Comment: I made a fiddle here:
http://viper-7.com/1dXwXQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work to get all of the combinations in a single regex: (updated form your fiddle)

```
$pattern = '/(\s-\s[0-9]+,[0-9]+€)|(\s-\s)$/';
$package_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $package_name);
echo $package_name;
```

Here is the regex in action: http://regex101.com/r/pR6jM9/3

And here is the code from the fiddle you supplied in the comment: http://viper-7.com/ZpivYn

Explanation of the regex:

get ' - ' followed by numbers followed by , followed by € symbol
or
get ' - ' at the end of a line

then replace it with nothing

Answer (score 2):

This is my attempt:

```
$pattern = '/\s*-\s*([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?€)?$/';
$package_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $package_name);
```

Not sure what $package name is. If it's a multiline paragraph, then you could use preg_replace_all.

Here's the demo:

http://regexr.com/39sev

Things that it will match:

```
 - 
 - 34€
 - 3500000€
 - 3,39€
 - 3,3999999€
```

It won't match:

```
 - ,99€ (nothing before ,)
 - 3, (nothing after ,)
 - 3 (no euro sign)
```

**Edit**: Whitespace fix ( - can have multiple or no whitespace before and after).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to remove everything after the last `-` and the minus itself.

You don't need a regex for that! Just determine the position of the last `-`, cut the string at this position and apply a `rtrim()` to the result to get rid of the last whitespaces:

```
$position     = strrpos($package_name, '-');
$package_name = substr($package_name, 0, $position - 1);
$package_name = rtrim($package_name);
```

This is much more general than the accepted answer. And you could do the same with regex if you want to:

```
$pattern = '/\s*-[^-]+$/';
$package_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $package_name);
```

Much simpler and working with every ending of your strings..

Comment: I think this is a much more better approach. You don't need to use strpos and then substr though, php got its own function for that: [strrchar](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php). So it can be easily done by `rtrim($package_name, strrchar($package_name, '-'));`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$pattern = '([0-9]+,[0-9]++â‚¬)';
$package_name = preg_replace($pattern, '', $package_name);

$package_name = trim($package_name, "-");
echo $package_name;
```

Use trim() to cut out the last "-".

Comment: Thank you for adding to the solution. It's good to know trim() is available as a backup solution.